# Delphi IDE hangs when I create a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, debugging, delphi-2010, virtualtreeview

I have a problem that Delphi (2010) IDE and the program both hang during debugging when I run a thread.
Both windows do not respond. When I kill the program, IDE works again.

It took time, I had to delete pieces of my program and I found the problem.
It is caused by VirtualStringTree.

So if I put just empty VirtualStringTree (v. 5.5.3) on form, one button to execute TThread with just "Sleep(2000)" in Execute procedure and run such program under debugger, it hangs (usually at first click).  When I remove the VST, it works.
I have also noticed that Windows Reporting Service is started but I haven't found anything in the Windows event log.

Does anyone have any idea how this is possible?

Full source here

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, VirtualTrees, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    VirtualStringTree1: TVirtualStringTree;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TTestThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TTestThread }

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  FreeOnTerminate:=True;

  Sleep(2000);
end;

{ TForm }    

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTestThread.Create(False);
end;

end.
```

**EDIT:**
I have also tried to debug Delphi process. I attached from second to first IDE. When I click the button to start the thread, both IDEs hang. So I have tried with Delphi 7 which I also have installed. That worked. It stays in a loop somewhere in ntdll.NtWaitForMultipleObjects, KERNELBASE.WaitForMultipleObjectsEx, USER32.MsgWaitForMultipleObjects.

I have completely reinstalled Delphi, no change. It may also be related to this line in VirtualStringTree source: "WaitForSingleObject(WorkEvent, INFINITE);". When I remove it, it does not freeze. But I think it is necessary there.

Finally I installed Delphi XE and that works correctly. It is mysterious.

Comment: It's not clear what the context is. Design time package. Executable running under the debugger? Or something else. Please give precise steps to reproduce.

Comment: I slightly modified it. Yes, it is executable under debugger. Just one VirtualStringTree and one button to run any TThread.

Comment: Can you include the full source of a small program that reproduces this? (Since it looks like a tiny program will reproduce it...)

Comment: Run two copies of the IDE, one debugging the other. Use that to find out where it's hanging.

Answer (score -1):

TTestThread is a descendant of TThread in your code but it still needs a variable declaration and a proper constructor call.

```
var
  MyThread: TTestThread;
```

The proper call to instantiate it would be

```
MyThread := TTestThread.Create(False);
```

rather than trying to invoke the constructor as you have in the button click event.

Good luck and have fun.

RP

Comment: Thanks for your attention but this is not the problem which causes IDE and program to hang. I usually use variables but it is not necessary for the test case. There is no difference if you use the variable or not, it does not cause any problems, it is just not held in a variable.

Comment: In fact @Radical, if you do add the variable as you propose (assuming local), then the compiler would generate a hint advising you the value assigned is not used. Furthermore, the compiler won't generate the code to set the variable - because there's no point.

Comment: @Craig - if the compiler is generating that hint then it's likely the base class is still being invoked directly (calling TTestThread as opposed to MyThread). 

RP

Comment: @Radical It seems to me you didn't understand my comment and/or you're misunderstanding some OO principles. **1)** The variable declaration has ***zero effect*** on how the object is constructed. `TTestThread.Create(False);` creates an instance of `TTestThread` because that's the name of the class for which the constructor is called. **2)** Yes, a parent/base implementation of `Create(Boolean)` will be called if not re-implemented on `TTestThread`, but this doesn't change the fact that the object constructed will be a `TTestThread` instance. _You can think of object construction as 2 steps:_

Comment: (cont.) _a) instantiate object. b) call constructor method on new object._ **3)** Now that that object exists, it's an entirely separate step to assign a reference to the new instance to `MyThread`. (It might help to think of `MyThread := TTestThread.Create(...)` as `TTestThread.Create(...) --> MyThread`) **4)** This assignment is pointless if you do not actually use `MyThread` before it goes out of scope.